# Error "File System Loop Detected" Permission Denied to Decrypt folder with ecryptfs-recover-private

Tags: find, root, luks, cryptsetup

I'm trying to open encrypted files from a full encrypted drive that is unlocked and mounted. I have tried various commands and have been unsuccessful.

How can we fix the find "file system loop detected" and the permission denied errors?

Could this be because its encrypted with LUKS and not ecryptfs? I was told it didn't matter when decrypting but I think that might not be true.

What command would I use if it's not the one I'm already using?

The errors I have received are below.

```
sudo ecryptfs-recover-private --rw /home/t/Downloads/RECOVERY LM DELL/.ecryptfs/guest/.Private
INFO: Searching for encrypted private directories (this might take a while)...
find: File system loop detected; ‘/run/timeshift/backup’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘/’.
find: ‘/run/user/1000/doc’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
```

```
sudo find / -type d -name ".Private"
find: File system loop detected; ‘/run/timeshift/backup’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘/’.
find: ‘/run/user/1000/doc’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
/media/t/18d3bf7a-2443-444a-a717-fb9c3b025700/home/.ecryptfs/guest/.Private
/home/.ecryptfs/t/.Private
/home/t/Downloads/RECOVERY LM DELL/.ecryptfs/guest/.Private
```

```
sudo bash
root@:/home/t# ecryptfs-recover-private
INFO: Searching for encrypted private directories (this might take a while)...
find: File system loop detected; ‘/run/timeshift/backup’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘/’.
find: ‘/run/user/1000/doc’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
```

Two other issues I have with the .Private encrypted folders are:

- file name length sizes are too long when transferring or copying files
- achieving root access for every single file in encrypted folders to copy or transfer

I was able to open the folders in root and change permissions for entire folder but not all files will give full permission to transfer.

I believe there is a way to change the file size but not exactly sure how to do that.

I would like to figure out how to decrypt the files, then I can proceed to fix the filename length and permission issue unless those two things are part of the process to decrypt the .Private folder.